# Does FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline() opens multiple instances of connections if its called multiple times in my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to explicitly handle user presence from .info/connected because it takes too long to change user state automatically because of active listeners so I just call **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline()** in my main activity's onDestroy method to ensure user disconnects as soon as he closes the app. Now what I'm wondering is I might be calling **goOnline()** multiple times when my app starts, would that open multiple instances of connection to database? or would it just check if I'm already connected and ignore the other goOnline() calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase client opens a single socket connection to the server per `FirebaseApp`/`FirebaseDatabase` instance. Calling `goOnline()` multiple times does not open extra connections.

Answer (score 1):

getInstance() basically guarants that you are dealing with Singleton - it is a one object, that can be accessed from different places throughout the application lifecycle and it should be the 'single' one.

Citing documenation: `goOnline()`

Resumes our connection to the Firebase Database backend after a previous 
    `goOffline()` call.

That means that as long as your are getting instance of the same database (notice url's may differ and then you may have to deal with multiple instances) calling `goOnline` would not affect in a bad way. It is obvious though that such repetitive calls are nowhere near good, so try to control them as possible to improve the quality and performance of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove listners once you set listners for the each time. Once we created value listers create some variable for that listner and remove once activity is in on stop.

```
  databaseReference.removeEventListener(shortCutBadgerValueListner);
```

Comment: I have a lot of ValueEventListeners in my app calling **goOffline()**  in my main activity's destroy method just seems easier to stop active listeners when the app is closed instead of removing them all one by one in onStop().